# Generating Java from XSD schemas, two attributes have the same name but different namespaces

Tags: xml, xpath, jaxb, xjc

Trying to generate Java code from an XSD schema where a `complexType` contains two attributes with identical names, but different namespaces.

```
<xsd:complexType name="CT_ImageData">
  <xsd:attribute ref="o:href"/>
  <xsd:attribute ref="r:href"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

`xjc` says: `[ERROR] Property "Href" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.`

Tried custom bindings:

```
    <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='CT_ImageData']">
        <bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='href']">
            <property name="originalHref"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
```

But my binding is not selecting the attributes: `[ERROR] XPath evaluation of ".//xs:attribute[@name='href']" results in empty target node`

How do I target just the `o` namespaced href attribute in my `bindings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.//xs:attribute[@ref='o:href']`.
It's just XPath there's no schema interpretation behind it. So make sure your XPath actually points to an existing node.